# Angular js $http 404 call WebApi

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, jquery-mobile, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to call my webservice using "$http". if call with "$ajax" working ok.

Example Jquery $Ajax working ok.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "Get",
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "http://localhost:60237/api/Get/Work",
        data: { cdUser: 1},
        dataType: "json",
        success: onDataReceived,
        error: onDataError
    });
    function onDataReceived(data) {
    }
    function onDataError() {
    }
```

Example Angular $htpp (Not Working)

```
app.controller('alertxxController', function ($scope, $http) {

    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:60237/api/Get/Work',
        params: 'cdUser=1'
    }).success(function (data) {
        alert("ok");
    }).error(function () {
        alert("error");
    });



});
```

Really do not know why not this calling. I can't identify the error, return 404 (Not Found).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your "params" option is wrong.

Try this:

```
$http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:60237/api/Get/Work',
        params: { cdUser: 1}
    }).success(function (data) {
        alert("ok");
    }).error(function () {
        alert("error");
    });
});
```

Comment: Correct! The docs for params state: "params – {Object.<string|Object>} – Map of strings or objects which will be serialized with the paramSerializer and appended as GET parameters." https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Sorry, really I looked at docs "a brief look", however not noticed("{}").
Thanks a lot!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think the syntax for $http in angular is

```
$http.get('url here').success(function (response) {}).error(function () {});
```